# mongoose update only selected field

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have one model

```
const ModelSchema = new Schema({
  assetObj: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: "untitled"
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      default: "unavailable"
    },
    pageNo: {
      type: Number
    }
  },

....
});
```

I want to update title only in this model.
So I make code in here.

```
let updateQuery = {};
updateQuery.assetObj = {
  title: 'New Title'
};
await Model.update({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set: updateQuery });
```

But result is removed description and pageNo in model.

How can I update only title in mongoose model?

Comment: use something lik this **await Model.update({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set: { assetObj.title : New Title'  }**

Comment: @Shubham Tiwari Thanks, So Like this? updateQuery = { "assetObj.title": 'New Title"}

Comment: it will override whole data

Comment: @ShubhamTiwari I solved my problem with your method. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer.
I need to change field name to "some.some".
So I changed like at.

```
let updateQuery = { "assetObj.title": 'New Title"};
await Model.update({ _id: req.params.id }, { $set: updateQuery });
```